# Eclipse Javafx and Android

Tags: android, eclipse, javafx, gluon

All the information on the internet including StackOverflow regarding using JavaFX with Eclipse to build Android apps seems dated or relies on Gluon as if it's free. It's not, at least not anymore. I'm trying to develop small closed-source apps and I don't make enough money to justify the Gluon developer license. Is there any tutorial on how to create an Android app with javafx without Gluon? Is it even possible or am I stuck having to make my Android apps without javafx?

Comment: Are you referring to [Gluon Mobile](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/) ? Seems to me like there is a free version.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now.

Comment: GluonFX plugin is free, Gluon plugin for [Eclipse](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_the_gluon_plugin_for_eclipse) is free, JavaFX runs on Android, for free, without any license. You only need a license if you use the Gluon Mobile library. See [samples](http://www.gluonhq.com/support/samples).

Comment: For closed-source apps you can only freely use JavaFX on Android via the Gluon tools if you abstain from the Attach library (GPL without CPE) and the Charm-Glisten library (proprietary license). @JoséPereda please correct me if I am wrong or if I missed something else.